# Array does not work on Powershell 2.0

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a question. I want to receive administrators users last password change time on my servers. I find a script, but it doesn't work with Powershell 2.0.   Can you help me?

```
function Get-LocalUser {
  [Cmdletbinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [String[]]$Computername = $env:Computername
  )

  Begin {
    #region  Helper Functions
    function  ConvertTo-SID {
      Param([byte[]]$BinarySID)

      (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($BinarySID,0)).Value
    }

    function Convert-UserFlag {
      Param  ($UserFlag)

      $List  = New-Object  System.Collections.ArrayList
      Switch  ($UserFlag) {
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x0001)  {[void]$List.Add('SCRIPT')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x0002)  {[void]$List.Add('ACCOUNTDISABLE')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x0008)  {[void]$List.Add('HOMEDIR_REQUIRED')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x0010)  {[void]$List.Add('LOCKOUT')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x0020)  {[void]$List.Add('PASSWD_NOTREQD')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x0040)  {[void]$List.Add('PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x0080)  {[void]$List.Add('ENCRYPTED_TEXT_PWD_ALLOWED')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x0100)  {[void]$List.Add('TEMP_DUPLICATE_ACCOUNT')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x0200)  {[void]$List.Add('NORMAL_ACCOUNT')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x0800)  {[void]$List.Add('INTERDOMAIN_TRUST_ACCOUNT')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x1000)  {[void]$List.Add('WORKSTATION_TRUST_ACCOUNT')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x2000)  {[void]$List.Add('SERVER_TRUST_ACCOUNT')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x10000)  {[void]$List.Add('DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWORD')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x20000)  {[void]$List.Add('MNS_LOGON_ACCOUNT')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x40000)  {[void]$List.Add('SMARTCARD_REQUIRED')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x80000)  {[void]$List.Add('TRUSTED_FOR_DELEGATION')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x100000)  {[void]$List.Add('NOT_DELEGATED')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x200000)  {[void]$List.Add('USE_DES_KEY_ONLY')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x400000)  {[void]$List.Add('DONT_REQ_PREAUTH')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x800000)  {[void]$List.Add('PASSWORD_EXPIRED')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x1000000)  {[void]$List.Add('TRUSTED_TO_AUTH_FOR_DELEGATION')}
        ($UserFlag  -bor 0x04000000)  {[void]$List.Add('PARTIAL_SECRETS_ACCOUNT')}
      }

      $List  -join ', '
    }
    #endregion  Helper Functions
  }

  Process {
    $adsi  = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computername"

    $adsi.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq  'user'} |  ForEach {
      [pscustomobject]@{
        UserName            = $_.Name[0]
        SID                 = ConvertTo-SID -BinarySID $_.ObjectSID[0]
        PasswordAge         = [math]::Round($_.PasswordAge[0]/86400)
        LastLogin           = if ($_.LastLogin[0] -is [datetime]){$_.LastLogin[0]} else {'Never logged  on'}
        UserFlags           = Convert-UserFlag -UserFlag $_.UserFlags[0]
        MinPasswordLength   = $_.MinPasswordLength[0]
        MinPasswordAge      = [math]::Round($_.MinPasswordAge[0]/86400)
        MaxPasswordAge      = [math]::Round($_.MaxPasswordAge[0]/86400)
        BadPasswordAttempts = $_.BadPasswordAttempts[0]
        MaxBadPasswords     = $_.MaxBadPasswordsAllowed[0]
        Groups              = $_.Groups() | Foreach-Object {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
      }
    }
  }
}

$env:Computername | Get-LocalUser |
  Where-Object{$_.Groups -contains 'Administrators'} |
  Select-Object userName, PasswordAge, LastLogin
```

That is the error is

```
Unable to index into an object of type System.Management.Automation.PSMethod.
At line:103 char:32
+   LastLogin = If ($_.LastLogin[ <<<< 0] -is [datetime]){$_.LastLogin[0]} Else{'Never logged  on'}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex

Unable to index into an object of type System.Management.Automation.PSMethod.
At line:103 char:32
+   LastLogin = If ($_.LastLogin[ <<<< 0] -is [datetime]){$_.LastLogin[0]} Else{'Never logged  on'}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex
```

Comment: Your code uses [PowerShell v3 features](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2012/06/13/new-v3-language-features/).

Answer (score 0):

As @Ansgar Wiechers has already mentioned ,you are utilising higher version features.

you can get the same information with powershell 2.0 like this:

```
$adsi  = [ADSI]"WinNT://${env:computername}"
$child= $adsi.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq  'user'}
$properties = $child | select -ExpandProperty properties
$properties|%{echo $_.name $_.lastlogin $_.passwordage}
# you can retrieve the value like this also
#$properties[0]["lastlogin"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. Commands works but the output is problematic.  

Support
228168
test
08 September 2016 Thursday 11:56:00
7678974
test2
10


Any idea?